# Bad class file magic or version NOT related with versions of JDK

Tags: java, android

This is definitely not a duplicate of other similar questions, since in my case no Java lower that 8 in used anywhere.
In fact, I am trying to built my Android app and a new version of jar libraries cause this problem.

The thing is that these libraries run only on Java 8 and I have only Java 8 installed in my system.

Any ideas on where I should look? I am stuck here for days.

Thanks!

Comment: You realize that Android does *not* use Java 8, right? So if you're trying to include versions of a library which *do* target Java 8, that would be the problem...

Comment: @JonSkeet previous versions run fine for me. Jar is compiled with jdk 8. You mean in pom.xml file all files should target 7?

Comment: Just to add that previous versions were also compiled with java 8

Comment: Whether it's pom.xml or whatever else controls the build, I *believe* (and I'm not an Android developer - I don't know how the conversion from jar files to dex files happens) that you should target JDK 7 bytecode. Note that compiling *with* Java 8 isn't the same as *targeting* Java 8.

Comment: Android *only* uses Java lower than 8.